# Run file not updating changes in GUI using Swing

Tags: java, swing

I'm doing a login screen with Swing. I edited the enable property of the only button that exists in the screen - the "Entrar", as shown in the picture below:

[Login screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8KT5.png)

But, when I hit Shift-F6 (Run file) it doesn't shows the change:

[Login Screen after running single file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKWn8.png)

Here's the code:

```java
package view;

import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.Document;
/**
 *
 * @author User
 */
public class Inicio extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    String usuario;
    String senha;

    int a;

    public Inicio() {  

        initComponents();

        DocumentListener dUsuario = new DocumentListener(){
            @Override
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                try {
                    usuario = e.getDocument().getText(0, 0);
                    a = 1;
                } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Inicio.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
            }

            @Override
             public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                try {
                    usuario = e.getDocument().getText(0, 0);
                    a = 1;
                } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Inicio.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }    

        };

        DocumentListener dSenha = new DocumentListener(){
            @Override
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                try {
                    senha = e.getDocument().getText(0, 0);
                    a = 2;
                } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Inicio.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
            }

            @Override
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                try {
                    senha = e.getDocument().getText(0, 0);
                    a = 2;
                } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Inicio.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }   

        };

        tUsuario.getDocument().addDocumentListener(dUsuario);
        tSenha.getDocument().addDocumentListener(dSenha);

        if(a == 2) {
            if (bEntrar.isEnabled() == false) {
                bEntrar.setEnabled(true);
            }

        }else{
            if (bEntrar.isEnabled() == true) {
                bEntrar.setEnabled(false);
            }

        }

    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        tSenha = new javax.swing.JPasswordField();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        tUsuario = new javax.swing.JFormattedTextField();
        bEntrar = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);

        jLabel1.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(153, 153, 153));
        jLabel1.setText("Informe apenas os dígitos do CPF.");

        jLabel2.setText("Senha:");

        jLabel3.setText("CPF:");

        jLabel4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel4.setText("LOGIN");

        try {
            tUsuario.setFormatterFactory(new javax.swing.text.DefaultFormatterFactory(new javax.swing.text.MaskFormatter("###.###.###-##")));
        } catch (java.text.ParseException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        bEntrar.setText("Entrar");
        bEntrar.setEnabled(false);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(184, 184, 184)
                .addComponent(jLabel4)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(0, 91, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING))
                .addGap(7, 7, 7)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                        .addComponent(tSenha, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(bEntrar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 129, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addComponent(tUsuario, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 128, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(55, 55, 55))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(50, 50, 50)
                .addComponent(jLabel4)
                .addGap(37, 37, 37)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3)
                    .addComponent(tUsuario, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(3, 3, 3)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addGap(9, 9, 9)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                    .addComponent(tSenha, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 58, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(bEntrar)
                .addGap(41, 41, 41))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        




    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Inicio.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Inicio.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Inicio.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Inicio.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Inicio().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton bEntrar;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JPasswordField tSenha;
    private javax.swing.JFormattedTextField tUsuario;
    // End of variables declaration                   


}
```

I edited the button properties using the Project view from Swing. So, what can I do to fix that? Is it a Netbeans bug? I'm using Netbeans IDE 8.2, by the way.

Comment: You need to change the state of the button in response to the changes of the UI, in this case, I'm guessing the `DocumentListener`s.

Comment: I changed the Button state before adding the DocumentListener, tested it, and it haven't updated either. I guess that the problem isn't there.

Comment: You need to set its initial state.  You then need to update it's state from WITHIN the `DocumentListener`s them selves - GUIs are event driven (not procedural), something happens (like the document been updated) and then your respond to it

Comment: *"Is it a Netbeans bug?"* Very unlikely, but you can check by running the code from a different IDE or launching it from the command line. In future, only mention / tag the IDE if you have already confirmed it works from another environment.

Comment: @MadProgrammer my code's doing that, isn't it? The thing is that I changed its initial state using the Properties menu (that one that's aside the code screen in the Project editing mode)

Comment: No, it's changing the variable `a` but nothing is acting on that, your `if-else` statement is out side of the scope of the event handling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to effect the state of the button based on changes which have occurred on the text fields, then those actions need to take place in the action handlers themselves (ie, the `DocumentListener`s)

The following is a very basic example, which disables the "action" button until both the user name and password fields are no longer empty

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JTextField userNameField;
        private JPasswordField passwordField;
        private JButton actionButton;

        public TestPane() {
            userNameField = new JTextField(15);
            passwordField = new JPasswordField(15);
            actionButton = new JButton("Do stuff");

            actionButton.setEnabled(false);

            DocumentListener documentListener = new DocumentListener() {

                protected void stateDidChange() {
                    actionButton.setEnabled(userNameField.getText().length() > 0 && passwordField.getPassword().length > 0);
                }

                @Override
                public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                    stateDidChange();
                }

                @Override
                public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                    stateDidChange();
                }

                @Override
                public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                    stateDidChange();
                }
            };

            userNameField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(documentListener);
            passwordField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(documentListener);

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = gbc.REMAINDER;


            add(userNameField, gbc);
            add(passwordField, gbc);
            add(actionButton, gbc);
        }

    }

}
```

> Why is the initial state not been updated?

You define `a` as....

```
int a;
```

which gives it a initial (or default) value of `0`.

You then use...

```
if(a == 2) {
    if (bEntrar.isEnabled() == false) {
        bEntrar.setEnabled(true);
    }
}else{
    if (bEntrar.isEnabled() == true) {
        bEntrar.setEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

to change the initial state.  Since `a` is `0`, the `else` block is executed, the only condition which would change the button enabled state to `false` would be if the current enabled state is `true`

> But when I use Shift+F6 to run the code it doesn't work

Do a "clean and build" and run the project, not the file.  In testing your code, the UI appears with the button already disabled